Compiling with gcc I get gcc can't find cc1 error. NOT a path problem, cc1 does not exist
I'm running gcc on a Raspberry 5.0 Debian OS latest Bookworm
Here is my gcc detail:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 12.2.0-14' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-12/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-12 --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
When i compile i get
"gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1’: execvp: No such file or directory"

I have tried
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
installs OK, doesn't fix problem.

The problem is not path related. If I run find from root (/), i do not find cc1 on my Raspberry anywhere. It's supposed to be part of gcc i presume.
Any ideas? I've tired removing and re-installing gcc, doesn't help.

This question is similar to: Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The trouble is that cc1 doesn't seem to exist on my machine even though gcc seems to be properly installed.

This could an issue with the Debian package, probably you should report to the maintainers. As an alternate you can try to download toolchains from other sources. The error most likely indicates "incompatible binary". Is Bookworm officially supported for RPi5 ?

Well, after an upgrade I noticed the Deb version was Bookworm, i didn't check the version when I bought it (recently). The gcc version that seemed to come with Bookworm was 4.x. I installed gcc version 12 but that didn't fix anything. cc1 is supposed to be part of gcc AFIK so I don't understand why it's not there. Maybe I'll try installing an older gcc.

OK, I tried running hello.c and got a can't find cc1 error. Decided to try same with a fresh OS install. It works AND, which cc1 returns nothing? Anyway, something I installed must have messed up gcc so I'll close this issue.
